# having issue with async.each , callback is geting call before completing task

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, loops, callback

i am having issue with async.each , callback is geting call before completing task, i have code below , get output as 
called reprice 7 executing before called reprice 6 , 6 is the part i am building an array that i need in  async.each callback

```
called reprice :
called reprice : 2
called reprice : 3
**called reprice : 7  []**
no chnages has been made 
called reprice : 6  { status: 200, msg: 'recived optimal price 4 ', data: 17.75 }
called reprice : 6  { status: 200, msg: 'recived optimal price 4 ', data: 20.99 }
```

**This is the code**

```
async.forEach(records, function(result, callback) {
    switch (result.Pricing) {
        case  "PF" : // current scenrio
            var pfObject = _.filter(rules, {'sub_title': 'PF'});
            checkRepriceFrequency(result, pfObject[0], function (response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    // call check inventory rules
                    CheckInventoryRules(result, pfObject[0], function (response) {
                        console.log('called reprice : 6 ',response);
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            var price = result.sales_price;
                            var pushData = {
                                price: price,
                                optimalPrice: response.data,
                                SKU: result.SKU,
                                _id: result._id,
                                frequency: pfObject[0].reprice_frequency
                            };
                            productArray.push(pushData);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('err');
                }
            });
        }
        callback(null);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('called reprice : 7 ',productArray);
    if (!err) {
        if (productArray.length > 0) {
            console.log('To update Synch : ',productArray);
        } else {
            console.log("no chnages has been made ");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi anyone can help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. So you implemented `async.each` a bit wrong. See, async.each makes sure that each object goes through the loop but doesn't ensure sync execution. In your example, you have called `CheckInventoryRules` which seems to do an AJAX call.

But check, you have called the callback at the end of the function (it does not wait for AJAX to complete). Which means before completing the AJAX call, the callback may have been called signaling that the processing of that particular object is done.

To fix it, you need to check that if AJAX call is being called, the `callback(null)` needs to be called after `productArray.push(pushData);`.

In general, call the `callback` only when the task has finished execution.

Comment: thank you @kawadhiya21 , right this is the problem , but if i am putting callback(null)  after productArray.push(pushData); , then callback is getting call after first push with the first match

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented async.forEach completely wrong.
[See this](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each).

There seems an async call in switch so you have to call **`callback(null)`** in that async call.

```
async.forEach(records, function(result, callback) {
    switch (result.Pricing) {
        case  "PF" :
            var pfObject = _.filter(rules, {'sub_title': 'PF'});
            checkRepriceFrequency(result, pfObject[0], function (response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    CheckInventoryRules(result, pfObject[0], function (response) {
                        console.log('called reprice : 6 ',response);
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            var price = result.sales_price;
                            var pushData = {
                                price: price,
                                optimalPrice: response.data,
                                SKU: result.SKU,
                                _id: result._id,
                                frequency: pfObject[0].reprice_frequency
                            };
                            productArray.push(pushData);
                            callback(null);
                        }
                    //handle callback on else otherwise final callback will not get the event.
                    });
                } else {
/*
                    callback(null);
                    Or
                    callback(Someerror);
*/
                    console.log('err');
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            callback(null);
        // return false;


        //break;


    }


}, function(err) {
    console.log('called reprice : 7 ',productArray);
    if (!err) {
        if (productArray.length > 0) {
            console.log('To update Synch : ',productArray);

        } else {
            console.log("no chnages has been made ");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you @vkstack i tryed like this but callback is executing with first match of "PF" ,

Comment: that's a practice to put default always in your switch statement.But choice is always yours.